# Find duplicates using SQL based on 3 values including Amount (Integer)

Tags: sql

I'm using an application that allows me to throw in SQL where I enter the Where clause of the select statement. The code below works. It returns all records where the Invoice Number and the Vendor Name are the same.  But I am not sure how to also include the AMOUNT field (Integer).  Whenever I try it breaks.

```
convert(nvarchar, Invoice Number+Vendor Name) in

(
select convert(nvarchar, Invoice Number+Vendor Name)
from TABLENAME
where Invoice Number is not NULL and 
group by convert(nvarchar, Invoice Number+Vendor Name)
having count(*) >1)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What do you mean by "include the AMOUNT field"?  Sample data and desired results would be a big help, as well as an explanation of the logic you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`.  Here is a representative query:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where exists (select 1
              from tablename t2
              where t2.number = t1.number and
                    t2.vendorname = t.vendorname and
                    t2.amount = t.amount
              group by t2.number, t2.vendorname, t2.amount
              having count(*) > 1
             )
```